# Serializing WPF DataTemplates and {Binding Expressions} (from PowerShell?)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization, powershell

Ok, here's the deal: I have code that works in C#, but when I call it from PowerShell, it fails.  I can't quite figure it out, but it's something specific to PowerShell. Here's the relevant code calling the library (assuming you've added a reference ahead of time) from C#:

```
public class Test {
   [STAThread]
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine(  PoshWpf.XamlHelper.RoundTripXaml(
           "<TextBlock Text=\"{Binding FullName}\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"/>"
      ) );
   }
}
```

Compiled into an executable, that works fine ... but if you call that method from PowerShell, it returns with no `{Binding FullName}` for the Text!

```
add-type -path .\PoshWpf.dll
[PoshWpf.Test]::Main()
```

I've pasted below the entire code for the library, all wrapped up in a PowerShell Add-Type call so you can just compile it by pasting it into PowerShell (you can leave off the first and last lines if you want to paste it into a new console app in Visual Studio.

To output (from PowerShell 2) as an executable, just change the -OutputType parameter to ConsoleApplication and the -OutputAssembly to PoshWpf.exe (or something).  Thus, you can see that running the **SAME CODE** from the executable gives you the correct output.

**But running the two lines as above or manually calling `[PoshWpf.XamlHelper]::RoundTripXaml` or `[PoshWpf.XamlHelper]::ConvertToXaml` from PowerShell just doesn't seem to work at all ... *HELP?!***

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace PoshWpf
{
    public class Test {
       [STAThread]
       public static void Main()
       {
          Console.WriteLine(  PoshWpf.XamlHelper.RoundTripXaml(
               "<TextBlock Text=\"{Binding FullName}\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"/>"
          ) );
       }
    }

   public class BindingTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
   {
      private static readonly TypeDescriptionProvider _DEFAULT_TYPE_PROVIDER = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(Binding));

      public BindingTypeDescriptionProvider() : base(_DEFAULT_TYPE_PROVIDER) { }

      public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
      {
         ICustomTypeDescriptor defaultDescriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
         return instance == null ? defaultDescriptor : new BindingCustomTypeDescriptor(defaultDescriptor);
      }
   }

   public class BindingCustomTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
   {
      public BindingCustomTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor parent) : base(parent) { }

      public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
      {
         PropertyDescriptor pd;
         var pdc = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(base.GetProperties(attributes).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());
         if ((pd = pdc.Find("Source", false)) != null)
         {
            pdc.Add(TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(typeof(Binding), pd, new Attribute[] { new DefaultValueAttribute("null") }));
            pdc.Remove(pd);
         }
         return pdc;
      }
   }

   public class BindingConverter : ExpressionConverter
   {
      public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
      {
         return (destinationType == typeof(MarkupExtension)) ? true : false;
      }
      public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
      {
         if (destinationType == typeof(MarkupExtension))
         {
            var bindingExpression = value as BindingExpression;
            if (bindingExpression == null) throw new Exception();
            return bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
         }

         return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
      }
   }

   public static class XamlHelper
   {
      static XamlHelper()
      {
         // this is absolutely vital:
         TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new BindingTypeDescriptionProvider(), typeof(Binding));
         TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(BindingExpression), new Attribute[] { new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(BindingConverter)) });
      }

      public static string RoundTripXaml(string xaml)
      {
         return XamlWriter.Save(XamlReader.Parse(xaml));
      }

      public static string ConvertToXaml(object wpf)
      {
         return XamlWriter.Save(wpf);
      }
   }
}



"@ -language CSharpVersion3 -reference PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase -OutputType Library -OutputAssembly PoshWpf.dll
```

Again, you can get an executable by just altering the last line like so:

```
"@ -language CSharpVersion3 -reference PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase -OutputType ConsoleApplication -OutputAssembly PoshWpf.exe
```

Comment: Incidentally, now that I've posted that, I notice I didn't really explain how this had anything to do with DataTemplates: basically, you have to produce XAML source to create a FrameworkTemplate of any type -- and I'm trying to create them from controls that have already been created, so I need to serialize back into XAML to do that.

Comment: Not sure about your immediate issue but you don't need to use XAML to create a DataTemplate in WPF (though you do with Silverlight.) In WPF you can use a tree of FrameworkElementFactory objects which are basically descriptors that include the element type, property setters, children, etc. But that's neither here nor there. Gotta think about this.

Comment: Yeah, I had a look at the FrameworkElementFactory, but it's a bit obtuse, and deprecated. The thing I'm MOST concerned about are pretty simple templates, with the data binding restricted to stuff like {Binding FullName} or {Binding Path=FullName} as shown in the example -- having found code that "works" I'd really like to use it and avoid generating my own Xaml strings ;)

Comment: Honestly, I'm only implementing it because it seemed simple when I came across the working example ;-) my previous answer was that templates have to be written in XAML, rather than generated by my PowerBoots DSL (because of the bindings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all this time (and considering the number of views this question has), it's worth coming back here to note that this is **fixed** in *PowerShell 3* -- I'm not sure if that's because they fixed a bug, or if it's because PS3 runs on *.Net CLR 4* or what.

Regardless, if you add `System.Xaml` to the list of `-reference` assemblies, the code in the original question works as-is in PowerShell 3 and 4. I guess I'll mark this as the answer, mostly so people can stop coming here to try and answer it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no powershell dev, but have you tried escaping the { } with ` ? Perhaps it's trying to be clever and evaluate the binding as a powershell expression?

Comment: That's a good thought.  In my test case, the {} are being inserted in the C# Main() method just for the purpose of avoiding such differences ... and I deliberately used Console.WriteLine so they're not "output" that will be parsed by PowerShell at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused about the TypeConverter setup you're doing in XamlHelper's type initializer. What is BindingConverter supposed to do? Are you intending for the {Binding} markup extension to be handled the way it normally does in WPF?

In any case, markup extensions *cannot* round trip through XAML which is by design. The following excerpt from an MSDN page regarding [XAML serialization limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx):

> Common references to objects made by
>   various markup extension formats, such
>   as StaticResource or Binding, will be
>   dereferenced by the serialization
>   process. These were already
>   dereferenced at the time that
>   in-memory objects were created by the
>   application runtime, and the Save
>   logic does not revisit the original
>   XAML to restore such references to the
>   serialized output. This potentially
>   freezes any databound or resource
>   obtained value to be the value last
>   used by the run-time representation,
>   with only limited or indirect ability
>   to distinguish such a value from any
>   other value set locally. Images are
>   also serialized as object references
>   to images as they exist in the
>   project, rather than as original
>   source references, losing whatever
>   filename or URI was originally
>   referenced. Even resources declared
>   within the same page are seen
>   serialized into the point where they
>   were referenced, rather than being
>   preserved as a key of a resource
>   collection

Given that, I'm not sure why on earth it should even work at all in a compiled application. But as I said, I must admit I am not sure what you're doing with the TypeConverter so maybe you've already addressed the above limitation.

Comment: The BindingConverter provides the save logic for the binding expression (without caring about the "source" per-se), which for now, is perfect for what I'm doing ... since we want to set the source later anyway.

Comment: Incidentally, the BindingCustomTypeDescriptor and BindingTypeDescriptionProvider actually do attempt to serialize the source in case it's a static-reference, but I haven't really got any useful examples of where I would use that (ie: where it would make sense to round-trip that), so I'm not really using it at the moment.

Comment: Check these for more details on BindingConverter - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/xamlwriterandbinding.aspx and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a1984451-4840-4e0f-abc5-8a8e34a4f8ca